# Remove double quotes from data frame while writing to csv

Tags: python, dataframe, double-quotes

I tried to include 3 lists into dictionary, convert to data frame and then write to csv

```py
dicti = {'X': list_X, 'Y': list_Y, 'Z': list_Z} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dicti) 
df2.to_csv('dataa.csv')
```

Output printed in csv

```
"9.0, 9.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2","10.0, 10.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2","18.0, 18.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2"
```

Expected output

```
9.0, 9.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2,10.0, 10.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2,18.0, 18.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2
```

Comment: Can you show what the dataframe looks like? And perhaps one of the lists...

Comment: X                                                                        
9.0, 9.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2       

10.0, 10.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2
12.5, 12.5, 3.5, 1.8708286933869707, 1.5

Comment: This is how my X column looks like, similarly I have values for Y and Z. Also each of the column belongs to list X, list Y and list Z respectively

Comment: Do the quotes show when your print the DataFrame in the console?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. My guess is that the data was not parsed correctly/properly.

Comment: I do not see the quotes while printing the data frame. They are absolutely fine. but when I try to write it in CSV, it shows each list as a string.

Comment: Below is the code that I had used         dfx_temp = x_df.iloc[i:j]
  list_X.append(str(calculateFeatures(dfx_temp)).strip('[]'))
  dfy_temp = y_df.iloc[i:j]
  list_Y.append(str(calculateFeatures(dfy_temp)).strip('[]'))
  dfz_temp = z_df.iloc[i:j]
  list_Z.append(str(calculateFeatures(dfz_temp)).strip('[]'))  
  dicti = {'X': list_X, 'Y': list_Y} 
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(dicti) 
  df2.to_csv('dataa.csv',index=False)

Answer (score 3):

While writing into csv, following code can be used in order to remove double quotes.
This parameter is an inbuit feature of `df.to_csv()`

```
df.to_csv('data2.csv',index=False,header= False,sep = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = ' ')
```

It worked for me and Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I believe the work you are doing here to populate list_X:

```
list_X.append(str(calculateFeatures(dfx_temp)).strip('[]'))
```

is actually resulting in a list that contains one string, which looks like this.

```
list_X = ['9.0, 9.0, 2.5, 1.5811388300841898, 1.2']
```

It looks a lot like a list of numbers, but it isn't.

What are the dimensions of your resulting df? If your lists each contain one string, the dimensions would be [1 rows x 3 columns].